# evaluate the function, is the procedure I used correct?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

The derivative of $f(x)= \frac{2}{(1-3x^2)^2}$ Would you expect difficulties evaluating this function for $x= 0.577?$ try it with 3 and 4 digit cutting arithmetic.
I have been guided by the attached Chapra Book which I took as a reference guys, I hope I have done everything correctly
$f(x) = \frac{2}{(1-3(0.577)^2)^2}= 1359278$
Using three-digit cut arithmetic we have:
$x = 0.577 $
$x^2=0.577^2= 0.332$
$3x^2= 3(0.332)= 0.996$
$1-3x^2= 1-0.996=0.004$

Then
$f'(0.577)= \frac{2}{(1-0.996)^2}= 125000$
The relative percentage error is equal to
$ \epsilon _t = | \frac{1359278-125000}{1359278}|= 90.8%$
When using 4-digit slice arithmetic
$x = 0.577 $
$x^2=0.577^2= 0.332929= 0.3329$
$3x^2= 3(0.332)= 0.9987$
$1-3x^2= 1-0.9987=0.0013$
Then
$f'(0.577)= \frac{2}{(1-9987)^2}= \frac{2}{0.0013^2}= 1183432$

The relative percentage error is equal to
$\epsilon _t = | \frac{1359278-1183432}{1359278}|= 12.9%$
Are the calculations I have made correct? I have been guided by an exercise from Chapra's Book that I will attach

[Ejercicio1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhOH3.jpg)

[Ejercicio2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5RXI.jpg)